# How tune LFR_benchmark_graph method in networkx for generating large graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to generate random community in below way:

```
from random import randint
import networkx
from networkx.algorithms.community import LFR_benchmark_graph

n = [250, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1900, 2000, 2500, 2800, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4600, 5000]
index = randint(0, len(n) - 1)
tau1 = 3
tau2 = 1.5
mu = 0.1
mm = randint(0, len(n) - 1)
G = LFR_benchmark_graph(n[index], tau1, tau2, mu, average_degree=5,
                        min_community=20, seed=10)
```

but rise mentioned error:

```
networkx.exception.ExceededMaxIterations: Could not assign communities; try increasing min_community
```

when I use size 250 I have any error, but when I want to use other sizes to generate a network with the random size, I get that error. How can I fix it?

Comment: There is also a `max_iters` argument that defaults to `500` according to the docs. You may want to try raising that.

Comment: no, I just want to create a graph with more than 500 nodes @YakymPirozhenko

Answer (score 1):

This is mentioned in the documentation page:

> Though the authors describe the algorithm as quite robust, testing
>   during development indicates that a somewhat narrower parameter set is
>   likely to successfully produce a graph. Some suggestions have been
>   provided in the event of exceptions.

Here are some configurations that worked for me:

```
def genrate_lfr_graph(size=250):
    params = {"n":size, "tau1":2, "tau2":1.1, "mu":0.1, "min_degree":20, "max_degree":50}

    G = LFR_benchmark_graph(params["n"], params["tau1"], params["tau2"], params["mu"], 
                        min_degree=params["min_degree"],
                        max_degree=params["max_degree"],
                        max_iters=5000, seed = 10,
                        )
    print("Generation Completed")
    return G  


sizes = [250, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1200, 2000, 2500, 2800, 3000]
for n in sizes:
    G = genrate_lfr_graph(size=n)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned at the documentation of networkx, such an error will occur if any of the below:

If a valid degree sequence cannot be created within max_iters number of iterations.
If a valid set of community sizes cannot be created within max_iters    number of iterations.
If a valid community assignment cannot be created within 10 * n *    max_iters number of iterations.

My recommendation is to firstly attempt using the parameters as they are described in any other paper. For example for a network with 1000 nodes I would use these parameters: n=1000, tau1=3, tau2=1.1, mu=0.1, avg_degree=10, max_degree=50, min_community=10,max_community=50.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this problem till I came across this paper "A Comparative Analysis of Community Detection Algorithms on Artificial Networks" and used its parameter initialization and it worked every time here a code snippet to use

```
from networkx.generators.community import LFR_benchmark_graph as lfr

def generate_graph(n_low=250, n_high=10000):
    n = np.random.randint(n_low, n_high)
    tau1 = 3
    tau2 = 1.5
    mu = np.random.uniform(0.03, 0.75)
    max_degree = int(0.1 * n)
    max_community = int(0.1 * n)
    average_degree = 20
    G = lfr(
        n,
        tau1,
        tau2,
        mu,
        average_degree=average_degree,
        max_community=max_community,
        max_degree=max_degree,
        seed=10,
    )
    return G
```